# Dictionary Creation from a multi layer class

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the following model:

```
public class IP_BankInfo
{
    public App.BankType BankType { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public List<IP_BankRows> Rows { get; set; }
}
public class IP_BankRows
{
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public List<IP_BankBindings> Bindings { get; set; }
}
public class IP_BankBindings
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public string ExpectedHeader { get; set; }
    public string TransactionPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Where for the post-processing, I am interested in `IP_BankBindings` - **ColumnIndex** and **TransactionPropertyName**. What I would like to do, is to create a new `Dictionary<int,string>` which will hold the above metioned.

I have tried to retrieve them via LINQ:

```
var items = info.Rows.Where(n => n.Bindings.Where(x => x.TransactionPropertyName.Length > 0));
```

However with no luck. Any suggestion would be welcome (maybe Dictionary is not the right type).

P.S. what I do afterwards is, that I have a CSV file which I read row by row, and these give me column index position and the target property I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the BankBindings using [SelectMany()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var query = info.Rows
    .SelectMany(r => r.Bindings)
    .Where(x => x.TransactionPropertyName != null && x.TransactionPropertyName.Length > 0);
```

> what I do afterwards is, that I have a CSV file which I read row by row, and these give me column index position and the target property I am interested in.

Do you mean TransactionPropertyName? To further get the ColumnIndex and TransactionPropertyName

```
var dataForCsv = query
    .Select(b => new { b.ColumnIndex, b.TransactionPropertyName});
```

You can then loop through dataForCsv, writing the two properties to your CSV file.

Comment: Fantastic and simple!